# Unable to Connect apache Cassandra on local machine

Tags: cassandra

I am new to Apache Cassandra, i had just install a Apache Cassandra 3.9.0(64-bit) on my local windows 8.1 64- bit laptop along with No-SQL manager for Cassandra.
When i tried to register server an error message displayed as "None of the hosts tried for query are available". 
Can anyone help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: Is you server started correctly? see any error available in start up logs, also mention your configuration in Cassandra.yaml file. Explain about your error in detail e.g. stack trace